# jQuery overlay -- Same code for different DIVs

Tags: jquery, css, overlay, loader

I am trying to do the following -->  I have a dynamic number of `DIV` elements ..  All stacked like such:

```
 __________________________________________
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                    DIV1                  |
|                                          |
 __________________________________________
 __________________________________________
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                    DIV2                  |
|                                          |
 __________________________________________
 __________________________________________
|                                          |
|                                          |
|                    DIV3                  |
|                                          |
 __________________________________________
```

I have a button on the inside of each that calls to the same jQuery function:

```
function updateProduct(old_q,ent_id,element){
        var new_q = jQuery(element).prev().children('input').val();
        jQuery.post('/ajax_calls/checkout/update_cart_item.php', {entity_id: ent_id,old_q: old_q,new_q: new_q}, function(data) {
                cartItemOut = data;
                alert(cartItemOut);
        });
}
```

As you can see, I use jQuery to determine what `THIS` element is, and then find the input relating to children/parent etc.  My question, is how do I overlay a "loading" `DIV` over the entirety of **either** `DIV1`, `DIV2` **or** `DIV3` given the code I use above to determine which `DIV` I am in?  Here is the basic structure of each `DIV`:

```
<div class="item_wrapper">
        <div style="float:left; width:100px; height:100px; margin-left:15px; position:relative;">
                <div style="margin-top:100%;"></div>
                <img width="100" height="69" src="/images/100/198.jpg" style="position:absolute; top: 0px; bottom: 0px; left: 0px; right: 0px; max-height:100%; max-width:100%; display:block; margin:auto;">
        </div>
        <div style="float:left; width:198px; margin-left:20px; margin-bottom:7px;">
                <div style="height:31px; overflow:hidden; margin-bottom:2px;">
                        <span style="font-size:12px; font-weight:bold;">Name</span>
                </div>
                <br> 
                <span style="color:#86a057;">item#: </span>198<br>
                <span style="color:#86a057;">price:</span>
                <span style="color:#000; font-weight:bold;">$107.99</span><br>

                <div style="width:300px; margin-top:10px;">

                       <div style="float:left; margin-top:4px; width:20px; margin-right:3px; color:#86a057;">qty: </div>

                       <div style="float:left; margin-right:15px;">
                       <input type="text" value="1" style="font-family:arial; font-size:13px; height:17px; margin-top:2px; width:30px; text-align: center;"></div>

                       <div onclick="updateProduct('1','198',this);" style="float:left; margin-right:7px; margin-top:3px;  width:59px; height:20px; cursor:pointer;">
                       <img src="/skin/frontend/templat/default/images/update_cart.png">
                       </div>

                       <div style="float:left; margin-right:7px; margin-top:3px;  width:59px; height:20px; cursor:pointer;">
                       <img src="/skin/frontend/template/default/images/remove_cart.png">
                       </div>

                </div>


        </div>
        <div class="clearfix"></div>
</div>
```

So in essence, the question is I have multiple `DIV`s with the class `item_wrapper`.  When I click on `updateProduct()` how do I cover **that** `DIV` with an overlay and loader image?  Everything I try seems futile, and I am beginning to think it's not possible with the realm of *simple*. I have tried even getting as complex as detecting `item_wrapper`'s position and `WIDTH`/`HEIGHT` and positioning a `FIXED` `DIV` over it, but that doesn't seem to be the right solution, there has to be a better way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can find the parent div with the following jQuery:

```
var itemWrapper = jQuery(element).parents('.item_wrapper');
```

Then you can append some loading element to that item and position and size it accordingly.

```
function updateProduct(old_q, ent_id, element) {
    var new_q = jQuery(element).prev().children('input').val();
    jQuery.post('/ajax_calls/checkout/update_cart_item.php', {entity_id: ent_id,old_q: old_q,new_q: new_q}, function(data) {
            cartItemOut = data;
            alert(cartItemOut);
            $(element).find('.loading-overlay').remove();
    });
    var $ = jQuery, itemWrapper = $(element).parents('.item_wrapper'),
        iHeight = itemWrapper.height(), iWidth = itemWrapper.width();
    itemWrapper.prepend($('<div class="loading-overlay"><span>Loading...</span></div>').height(iHeight).width(iWidth));
}
```

It looks like another answer already mentions this, but you need to use absolute positioning to cover your elements.

```
.loading-overlay {
    position: absolute;
    background: gray;
    z-index: 1;
    opacity: 0.5;
}
```

Here's a fiddle using something similar to what you've got: http://jsfiddle.net/Jeff_Meadows/dyPMG/3/

Comment: This is really close to what I need.  Thank you very much, it helped point me in the right direction!

Answer (score 1):

You can use absolute positioning to mask the element. You can enhance example given below.

```
<div class="ct">
    <div class="x">
        <input type="button" Value="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <input type="button" Value="Test" />
    </div>
    <div class="x">
        <input type="button" Value="Test" />
    </div>
</div>

$('.ct').on('click', '.x input', function(e){
    var target = $(e.target);
    var div = target.closest('.x');
    div.append('<div class="mask">mask</div>');
    setTimeout(function(){
        $('.mask', div).remove();
    }, 2500);
});

.ct {
    padding: 10px;
}

.x {
    height: 50px;
    margin-bottom: 10px;
    border: 1px solid lightgrey;
    position: relative;
}

.mask {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    right: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    opacity: .5;
    background-color: lightblue;
}
```

Demo: [Fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/arunpjohny/6zL9U/3/)